# Url rewrite but keeping the file name?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanted to know if it's possible to rewrite a url in .htaccess for get parameters but keep the filename?

```
"/file.php?name=myname" to "/file/myname/"
```

This code I am using currently replaces file.php with the value of name.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /file.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

I've searched around and I can't find any answers for this situation.

Comment: `$1` substitutes for the first `(..)` match group. The second capture would be in `$2`.

Comment: OH, Thanks! looks like i've found my answer :)

    "RewriteRule ^(file)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]"

Works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mario for the tip. I have found the answer to my question

```
RewriteRule ^(file)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]
```